# Through your help or with your help

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is correct and why?

Through your help I became a better person.

or

With your help I became a better person.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are possibilities, but "with your help" is more common and more idiomatic.

I view "**through**" as making a stronger statement. It suggests to me that the help is the primary reason that you were able to be a better person. "**With**" doesn't come off quite as strong, but it's more idiomatic, which is possibly why "through" sticks out as stronger.